# Raspberry Pi Audio Bridge

Tags: audio, bluetooth, bridge

I would like to connect audio from a TV to be received into a Raspberry PI and then be transmitted via Bluetooth to a wireless Bluetooth speaker, is that possible? If so, how? Audio card?